# Sql query print one record overwrite if both action are present overwrite and insert

Tags: mysql, database, plsql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfX8F.jpg)Output gives overwrite when action is insert and overwrite both,
When  only one row (insert/overwrite) is present it should just give that one row

Comment: I don't understand what you need. If you could add some sample data and expected results that would help a lot

Comment: In  Sql table:-
SAMPLE_DATA
Overwrite
Insert
Overwrite Insert
Insert Overwrite
Insert
Overwrite

 ****I want to print *****.    Overwrite
Insert
Overwrite
Overwrite
Insert
Overwrite

Comment: Unfortunately, everything you wrote so far is very difficult to understand.

Comment: I've had a go, if only to demonstrate how to ask the question better - if you included the create and insert statements I show, and then a table showing the expected output (in the question, not a comment where its unformatted) it would be much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89c941/3

```
create table data(id int, action varchar(50));

insert into data(id, action) values(1,'Insert'),(2,'Overwrite'),(3,'Insert Overwrite'),(4,'Overwrite Insert')

select id, 
  action, 
  case when action like '%Overwrite%' 
    then 'Overwrite' 
    else action 
  end as Output
from data
```

Comment: No problem. Also etiquette is to upvote and accept the answer, so I get sweet internet points :)

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE userData(_id INT, name VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO data(id, name) VALUES(1,'abc'),(2,'xyz')

SELECT `_id, case WHEN name LIKE '%xyz%' THEN 'xyz' ELSE name  end AS Output` FROM userData;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).